# using extended euclidean algorithm to find s, t, r

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, cryptography, euclidean-algorithm

i am stuck for many hours and i don't understand using the extended euclidean algorithm. i calculated it the gcd using the regular algorithm but i don't get how to calculate it properly to obtain s,t,r.

i understand that from the gcd i can get a linear combination representation, but i don't get how to do it using the algorithm.

how can i find $s,t,r$ for $a=154, b= 84$?

if it is of any importance, the algorithm i am referring to is from the book cryptography: theory and practice

thank you very much. became hopeless because of it

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please, format maths on this site using LaTeX, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). There is also a [quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thank you.

Comment: edited my post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Euclidean algorithm, we have

$$
\begin{align}
154&=1\cdot84+70\tag{1}\\
84&=1\cdot70+14\tag{2}\\
70&=5\cdot14+0
\end{align}
$$
The last nonzero remainder is 14. So $\gcd(154,84)=14$. Now
$$
\begin{align*}
14&=84-70\qquad\text{(using 2)}\\
&=84-(154-84)\qquad\text{(using 1)}\\
&=2\cdot84-1\cdot154
\end{align*}
$$
So $14=2\cdot84-1\cdot154$.

Comment: thank you so much for making this clearer